# Android app stuck on launching - showing the white screen

Tags: android, android-support-library, androidx

The app stuck forever and showing the white screen when launching it. I have put a log in splash activity onCreate, but it doesn't reach to that line as well.

The recent change I did, was to migrate to androidX support libraries and as I can remember this started to happen after updating the libs in gradle file.

If I launch the app 10 times out of 2, will proceed to splash and work fine.

This is the dependencies list,

```
dependencies {
implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
androidTestImplementation('androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.0-beta02', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.3.4'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.6'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-perf:16.2.3'
implementation('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.7.1@aar') {
    transitive = true
}
implementation 'androidx.dynamicanimation:dynamicanimation:1.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
implementation 'androidx.annotation:annotation:1.0.1'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.0-alpha3'
implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.0.0'
implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.33.0'
implementation 'io.card:android-sdk:5.5.1'
implementation 'com.apollographql.apollo:apollo-runtime:0.3.2'
implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.10.0'
implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.8.0'
implementation 'jp.wasabeef:glide-transformations:3.3.0'
implementation 'com.wang.avi:library:2.1.3'

implementation 'com.braintreepayments.api:braintree:2.16.0'
implementation 'com.braintreepayments.api:drop-in:3.7.0'

def work_version = "1.0.0-alpha10"
implementation "android.arch.work:work-runtime:$work_version"

implementation 'io.supercharge:shimmerlayout:2.1.0'
implementation 'com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:2.7.0'
```

}

**UPDATE:** - added the log file

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.firebase.perf.internal.RemoteConfigManager
    at com.google.firebase.perf.internal.RemoteConfigManager.zzcb(Unknown Source:17)
    at com.google.firebase.perf.internal.FeatureControl.<init>(Unknown Source:2)
    at com.google.firebase.perf.internal.FeatureControl.zzar(Unknown Source:10)
    at com.google.firebase.perf.internal.GaugeManager.<init>(Unknown Source:4)
    at com.google.firebase.perf.internal.GaugeManager.zzbf(Unknown Source:22)
    at com.google.firebase.perf.internal.SessionManager.<init>(Unknown Source:4)
    at com.google.firebase.perf.internal.SessionManager.<clinit>(Unknown Source:39)
    at com.google.firebase.perf.internal.SessionManager.zzcn(Unknown Source:1)
    at com.google.firebase.perf.metrics.AppStartTrace.onActivityCreated(Unknown Source:37)
    at android.app.Application.dispatchActivityCreated(Application.java:220)
    at android.app.Activity.onCreate(Activity.java:1048)
    at androidx.core.app.ComponentActivity.onCreate(ComponentActivity.java:75)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.onCreate(FragmentActivity.java:335)
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.onCreate(AppCompatActivity.java:85)
    at activity.SplashActivity.onCreate(SplashActivity.java:22)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7144)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7135)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1271)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2931)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3086)
    at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1816)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
```

So if someone has a fix for this let me know.

Thanks

Comment: You need to share your code with question also read how to create [mcve]

Comment: what is the error, try and check error log

Comment: @KaranMer updated the question

Answer (score 0):

Seems like this is a [bug](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/firebase-talk/7Ccu-Zh8pdg) in firebase performance metrics lib. I downgraded from 16.2.3 to 15.0.0 and it works fine.